# How to get larger thumbnails for Facebook page link posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been successfully fetching only photos posted at my Facebook page via Opengraph api and now I want to display some links shared at the page through the similar method that I've been using to fetch photos.

The problem is that `type=link` posts don't contain `object_id`, which can be used to fetch a bigger thumbnail for photos like `https://https://graph.facebook.com/<%= post['object_id'] %>/picture`. What a `type=link` post returns is as follows.

#### Response

```
"id": "127100524044142_757791214308400",
"from": { ... },
"to": { ... },
"message": "...",
"message_tags": { ... },
"picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQA5ofIEKR1dK6_T&w=158&h=158&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fyeondoo.kr\u00252Fassets\u00252Fstaffs-88e474e70d16794e898d5f4bb200f710.jpg",
"link": "...",
"name": "...",
"caption": "...",
"description": "...",
"icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
"privacy": {
    "value": ""
},
"type": "link",
"status_type": "shared_story",
"created_time": "2015-01-25T06:08:11+0000",
"updated_time": "2015-01-25T07:54:28+0000",
"likes": { ...
    ],
    "paging": { ... }
},
"comments": { ...
    ],
    "paging": { ... }
}
```

I could get the url for "small" thumbnails via `picture` property, but this is too small to display on the website. Is there any solution to get a larger thumbnail for Facebook page, if that matters although I don't think it would, link posts via Opengraph API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happen to find a field which is not specified as default. It is `full_picture` and it returns the url for the "larger" thumbnail.

#### /posts?fields=full_picture

```
"full_picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBHe3GKoga49ZHw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fyeondoo.kr%2Fassets%2Fstaffs-88e474e70d16794e898d5f4bb200f710.jpg", 
"id": "127100524044142_757791214308400", 
"created_time": "2015-01-25T06:08:11+0000"
```